# Java Spring reference PropertySource relative to jar file

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jar

There are some external configuration files I would like to be able to configure from outside of the application jar file. The configuration files are being loaded with @PropertySource, similar to what you see below;

```
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/myFile.properties)
```

The application is found in a directory relatively placed with this configuration directory, see below.

```
\Workingdirectory
--\configuration
+++myfile.properties
--myApp.jar
```

How can I set the classpath to expect this relatively placed directory?

Comment: The general rule is that those runtime overrides should be in command-line arguments or environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the "file:" schema to relate outer resource

```
PropertySource("file:${app.home}/app.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where is app.home derived from? Is this specific to java spring?

Answer (score 0):

### @PropertySource("file:app.properties")

In a maven project (having no modules) the root of the project where you usually find the `pom.xml`.

In a maven project (having multiple modules) the folder of the main project. If you have in example this:

```
- my-project (located in /home/you/git/)
  - my-webapp
    - src
      + main
      + test
    pom.xml
  + library1
  + library2
  pom.xml
  app.properties <-- this is used

 localhost[/home/you/git/my-project]# mvn tomcat:run
```

### @PropertySource("app.properties")

In a maven project (having no modules) means the current classloader's classpath (usually located in `src/main/resources`).

### @PropertySource("file:/app.properties")

Means in windows the `C:\app.properties`.